# hackerrank birthday cake (I almost got but something wrong)

Tags: python-3.x

For example, if your niece is turning  4 years old, and the cake will have 4  candles of height 4, 4, 1, 3, she will be able to blow out 2 candles successfully, since the tallest candles are of height 4 and there are  such 
2 candles.

Sample Input

4

3 2 1 3

Sample Output

2

Here's my code

```
def birthdayCakeCandles(ar):
    candle = []

    for i in ar:
        if ar[i] == max(ar):
            candle.append(ar[i])

    print(len(candle))
```

In Pycharm, there's something trouble in """if[i] == max(ar)"""
It says index error but I don't know why it causes index error..

Comment: `if i == max(ar)`, `ar[i]` would work if you're iterating through integers from 0 to the length of `ar`, what you *are* doing is iterating through every element in `ar` so the element is defined as `i`

Comment: You are mixing two concepts on how to iterate on a list! Check my answer for both approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing two concepts on how to iterate through a list.
Also we don't need a list, we just need a variable `candles` which keeps count of number of valid candles

The first way is to pick each element in the list and use it, we do it by doing `for elem in list`, where `elem=4,4,1..`

```
def birthdayCakeCandles(ar):
    candles = 0
    #Maximum value in array
    max_arr = max(ar)
    #a in an element in ar
    for a in ar:
        if a == max_arr:
            candles+=1

    print(candles)
```

The second method is to get the indexes of the list and use those indexes to iterate, i.e. `for i in range(len(ar))` where `i=0,1,2...` etc.

```
def birthdayCakeCandles(ar):
    candles = 0

    max_arr = max(ar)
    #i is the index in ar
    for i in range(len(ar)):
        if ar[i] == max_arr:
            candles+=1

    print(candles)
```

In both cases, the output is `2`

Comment: Thank u for answering and I understand your code. but when I ran my code in Hackerrank, why do i get this message?? "Terminated due to timeout "  
I tried using both of code you suggested.

Comment: IF I remember correctly, you need to return the output in the function, are you doing that?

Comment: if u mean "return candles", I did it

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: I hadn't written "max_ar = max(ar)"  and when I add it, 
I got success message.
Is there difference between add it or not?

Comment: That is the line which gives you the maximum in the array, you need it

Comment: I mean we can write code without "max_ar = max(ar)"
cause we can use "if i == max(ar)